# How can I create a sliding layout, like the main android menu?

Tags: android

I need to create an application with 4 view. I need to pass from a view to an other simply by a touch and a move to the left or to the right (no button). The effect I would like is the same that you see when you navigate in the main menu of android when you pass from a page to another.

I have tested the ViewFlipper, but I cannot use it: it seems not to catch the touch event correctly. I don't even know if it is the right component.

What is the right way to handle this?

Comment: More details: in the main view of android, usually on the bottom, there are some bullets, meaning that you are on page 1, 2 or other. You can change page by using one finger and moving left or right. Some one can help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally I made it. This is my solution.
First of all you need to define a main layout, that contains the child layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >


<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/ViewFlipper01" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <include android:id="@+id/libraryView1"  layout="@layout/page_1" />
    <include android:id="@+id/libraryView2"  layout="@layout/page_2" />


</ViewFlipper>

</RelativeLayout>
```

where page_1 and page_2 are the layout that I need to exchange. Those layout are absolutely standard layout, made as you prefear.

Then you need an activity:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    private ViewFlipper vf;

    private float oldTouchValue;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        vf=(ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.ViewFlipper01);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {
        switch (touchevent.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            {
                oldTouchValue = touchevent.getX();
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            {
                //if(this.searchOk==false) return false;
                float currentX = touchevent.getX();
                if (oldTouchValue < currentX)
                {
                   vf.setInAnimation(inFromLeftAnimation());
                   vf.setOutAnimation(outToRightAnimation());
                    vf.showNext();
                }
                if (oldTouchValue > currentX)
                {
                    vf.setInAnimation(inFromRightAnimation());
                    vf.setOutAnimation(outToLeftAnimation());
                    vf.showPrevious();
                }
            break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    //for the previous movement
    public static Animation inFromRightAnimation() {

        Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  +1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
        );
        inFromRight.setDuration(350);
        inFromRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        return inFromRight;
        }
    public static Animation outToLeftAnimation() {
        Animation outtoLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
         Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  -1.0f,
         Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
        );
        outtoLeft.setDuration(350);
        outtoLeft.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        return outtoLeft;
        }    
    // for the next movement
    public static Animation inFromLeftAnimation() {
        Animation inFromLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
        );
        inFromLeft.setDuration(350);
        inFromLeft.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        return inFromLeft;
        }
    public static Animation outToRightAnimation() {
        Animation outtoRight = new TranslateAnimation(
         Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  +1.0f,
         Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
        );
        outtoRight.setDuration(350);
        outtoRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        return outtoRight;
        }    
}
```

Tada! Done!

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is a [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html). With that, you could so something like this:

```
<SlidingDrawer
     android:id="@+id/drawer"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"

     android:handle="@+id/handle"
     android:content="@+id/content">

     <ImageView
         android:id="@id/handle"
         android:layout_width="88dip"
         android:layout_height="44dip" />

     <GridView
         android:id="@id/content"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" />

 </SlidingDrawer>
```

Comment: Good effect, but not what I need: I need to change page, not to minimize on the bottom a page.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like the home screen where you can swipe between views and it snaps at each one?
[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/ViewFlipper_Animation.aspx) might help you out.

Comment: Yes! The link helped me, but is non a good sample because contains errors and some unexplained feature. I will post the  complete solution I made.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use layout animation for the purpose..

res/anim/popin.xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
  <scale
    android:fromXScale="0.0" android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0" android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="400" 
  />
</set>
```

res/anim/popinlayout.xml:

```
<layoutAnimation 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:delay="0.5"
  android:animationOrder="random"
  android:animation="@anim/popin" 
/>
```

Source:

```
// Applying a Layout Animation and Animation Listener
aViewGroup.setLayoutAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
  public void onAnimationEnd(Animation _animation) {
    // TODO: Actions on animation complete. 
  }
  public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation _animation) {}
  public void onAnimationStart(Animation _animation) {}
});

aViewGroup.scheduleLayoutAnimation();
```

Comment: I don't need an animation. Animation is a bonus: I need to change the layout.