# Vertical sliding menu in Android

Tags: java, android, android-menu, android-sliding

Is there a vertical sliding menu available for android. I need something similar to Sliding menu of the Google Plus App BUT I need it to be able to slide vertically from bottom to top also.

[image: Google Plus Sliding menu]

Comment: Use `ViewPager`. It will give you facility to view one page per screen. Though you can change `Page` size and view `more then one` page per screen and swipe horizontally.

Comment: @Dixit Patel My initial idea was to use Sliding Drawer for the side navigation too but I saw that it doesn't have a very good reputation and more important it is deprecated from the latest APIs. Do you think it is a decent choice. The design of the app I am making requires me to have 3 different sliding drawers(left, right and bottom of screen).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This UI Pattern is currently being referred to as Side Navigation and discussed in some detail here:

http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/06/emerging-ui-pattern-side-navigation.html

I think this is what you are looking for :)

https://github.com/korovyansk/android-fb-like-slideout-navigation

The side navigation isn't (yet) included in the Android SDK. A quick search in github does reveal one project that has implemented the UI pattern.

Here's another library project:

https://github.com/darvds/RibbonMenu

Two more library project:

https://bitbucket.org/jfeinstein10/slidingmenu/overview
https://github.com/Gregadeaux/android-fly-in-app-navigation

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @gosho_ot_pochivka if my answer helpful to you,don't forget to accept and upvote it :)

Comment: thanks I appreciate your answer. I have seen some of these projects but they all seem to have the sliding menu appear from left or right. I need to also be able to make it slide from bottom of the screen.

Comment: it means that there should be some handle(cotrol) at the bottom of the screen and when I press/pan it the menu should appear. The menu should slide from the lower left and right corners of the screen upwards. Hope this describes what I need. Something as an alternative to the SlidingDrawer.

Comment: curious about the solution, @gosho_ot_pochivka. Did you get one of these to actually slide vertically, or, did you settle for side sliding?

Comment: Very good answer, but now the navigation drawer is an official android widget, with its own design http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html and dev entries http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Answer (score 5):

First up all ,

I think sliding menu is used for navigation between views in standard UI pattern see [Drawers](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html), So if you are using for same purpose then don't display it from bottom, It will confuse your user.

If you want to implement similar you can refer to [link_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057367/exact-procedure-to-add-jfeinstein10-slidingmenu-in-android-project) , [link_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928488/how-can-i-create-a-sliding-layout-like-the-main-android-menu)

else, if you still want from bottom there are some links, like

[How to create bottom menu like gmail android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855148/how-to-create-bottom-menu-like-gmail-android),

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-create-android-menus/,

[Android SlidingDrawer from top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695856/android-slidingdrawer-from-top/11227689#11227689),

http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=16622,

http://androidblogger.blogspot.in/2009/01/sliding-drawer-again.html

[Android SlidingDrawer from top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695856/android-slidingdrawer-from-top/11227689#11227689)

There is also on deprecated [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/menu_design.html) but you can still refer it for just idea

Answer (score 1):

You can scroll the screen by 80% by calculating its width i have also implemented the same thing by programming only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a sliding menu implementation which has a vertical sliding menu, but there is a Sliding Menu implementation which uses the standard sliding menu. I think the most work is done there, so you could try to change it and make it appear vertically.

This is the implementation, which I use in my application. [click](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

It is very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

@AndroidLearner answer was very good when he wrote it.
However, since then, Google published its own implementation & design guidelines concerning the Navigation Drawer :
http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html