# Android slide up window

Tags: java, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

Can anyone point me to an example, or a lib to use for a slide up window.  I have an app and on an action I want to slide a window up from the bottom of the screen that displays info to the user.

I would like the window to slide up only a little bit to show the info.  Kind of like a hnt to the user, maybe 1/4 way up the screen.

This window can be manually dismissed or on a timer. I am looking to do this with **xamarin**, but a java example would also help.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you can use TranslateAnimation to do this.

Comment: Ahhh, yes, that is what I wanted an example of, to see how I would create the window and use TranslateAnimation to show it.

Comment: is this you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452938/vertical-sliding-menu-in-android

Answer (score 1):

You might have to change some of the variables in this method. 
I use this one in one of my apps. Animates a relativeLayout from bottom to top

```
 private void animate(){
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.yourLayout);
        AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

        Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.85f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f
                );
        animation.setDuration(250);
        set.addAnimation(animation);

        LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(set, 0.25f);
        rl.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that looks great, thanks!!!  Does that slide it up all the way, ideally I would like to only slide it up 1/4 of the way, or less… sort of like a hint to the user.

Comment: you can control the "amount of sliding" in the TranslateAnimation constructor parameters.

Comment: Change the values inside new TranslateAnimation(). If you copy paste the code inside Eclispe you can get a popup of what value you should change to get what you want :)

Comment: I will fool with it, thank you.  I am looking at the api call know to see the params.  If I run into a something, I know where to go!!!

Comment: So,when I try basically the same as the code above findViewById always returns null, what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I dont think your layout has been loaded, thats usually why it returns null. Post your code and Ill have a look.